# android: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() in doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runtime-error

I want to add to `EditText` few `ClickableSpan` in `AsynkTask`.

I used the next code for this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        ...

        class makeLinksAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, EditText> {

            private EditText buffer;

            protected EditText doInBackground(String... texts) {
            buffer = new EditText(context); // here is an error
                SpannableString spanStr = new SpannableString("word");
                ...
                buffer.append(spanStr);

                return buffer;
           }

           protected void onPostExecute(EditText linkedText) {
           ed.setText(linkedText.getText());
           }
     }
}
```

When I tested this code in different emulators and on my own device with Android2.3 everything was fine and this code worked well. But after uploaded apk to the GooglePlay I obtained few crash reports with bugs in mentioned line.
Log report is the next:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
...
at lubart.apps.dictionary.DictionaryActivity$makeLinksAsync.doInBackground(DictionaryActivity.java:2233) // this line is mentioned in code
```

Also I should say, that this problem appear not in all devices, some users reports that everything work fine.

Can you help me with with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    ...

    class makeLinksAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, SpannableStringBuilder> {

        protected SpannableStringBuilder doInBackground(String... texts) {
            SpannableStringBuilder buffer = new SpannableStringBuilder()

            ...
            buffer.append("word").append(...)...;

            return buffer;
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(SpannableStringBuilder linkedText) {
            ed.setText(linkedText);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not manipulate UI components (such as `EditText`) in a background thread.

Just make sure you do not interact with any `EditText` in your `doInBackground` method.

Comment: If you have to manipulate UI components from a background thread, you can still use `MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(..)` from your task's `doInBackground` method

Comment: yep, but in that case manipulation actually happens on UI thread :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! +1, for sure, but j0n0's answer more close to my case. Thank you!